# Определение близлежайших городов по IP

Tags: ip, картография

Добрый день! Внедряем определение геопозиции на сайте и последующий редирект.
Мы имеем 11 городов по России и каждый из них на своем поддомене. Определяем по IP и выдаем город в модалке "Ваш не Ваш", вопрос такой что если определенный город не входит в наши 11 можно ли выдавать ему самый ближайший по отношению к нашим, есть что то проработанное для таких целей?

Спасибо за внимание, благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Заводите в базе **все** областные центры и в каждом указываете через какой из 11 поддоменов работать.
2. Определяете город пользователя по IP
3. Если от города зависит список предоставляемых услуг, то просите подтвердить город
4. Если не зависит, то просто редиректите пользователя на нужный домен
5. Если пользователь оказался с другой страны - редиректите на тот домен, который считаете нужным

Comment: Спасибо, Антон!